# mysql php displays results but not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I stripped down query for only one insert

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'cstring.php';
$title="";
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {
    $title=$_POST['title']; 
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into blogpages(blogpagetitle) values('".$title."')");
    if($query){
        $bloga="sucessfully added a new blog";
        echo $bloga; 
     }
     else {
        echo mysqli_error($con); // if using mysqli do not use mysql in between
     }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

is there something wong in this code that it doesnt insert into mysql

table structure

1.bpid int(50)--------------null-no default-none autoincrement

2.blogpagetitle------------varchar(255) utf16_general_ci

3.datemade-------------timestamp current time stamp

4.blogpagedescription---------text utf16_general_ci

5.blogbody----------------longtext utf16_general_ci

6.blogpageextended------------ text utf16_general_ci

Comment: What is the structure of your `blogpages` table?

Comment: To display errors correctly you need to have:
print mysqli_error($con);

Comment: Also I really hope this code is much simplified for SO. NEVER take a post value and insert it straight into a DB, always use something like:

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);

Comment: no errors displayed or query inserted.

Comment: please show one of these failing insert-statements.. And please check with `if(mysqli_error())` if the query is failing

Comment: To print the error you should use `mysqli_error($con)` and not `mysql_error()`.

Comment: now working after changing the Collation for each row of table

Comment: @SACHINHD can you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842451/mysql-php-displays-results-but-not-inserting-into-database#comment42249121_26842451) and change your question with more info about the error?

Answer (score 1):

**TIP**

1. Sanitize variables, Use mysqli_real_escape_string()
2. When you are not able to debug your code, echo every possible stuff and die the rest code.
   For example here, echo if there is error in DB connection, echo the query to see if it is correct, echo the result of query execution, echo if there is some error!

Comment: No no. `echo mysql_error();}` is closing `else {
    $title=$_POST['title'];` [Check it yourself](http://beta.phpformatter.com/).

Comment: indentation!  God! Let me keep the tips and delete the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using echo mysql**i**_error($con) to get the error message rather than mysql_error().